# Is anyone able to help convert this code from Java to .Net (vb or c#)

Tags: java, .net

I'm having a bit of trouble converting this snippet of code from java to .net, in this case to vb.net, but I'm happy to convert from c# to vb if someone can help get it to that.

I'm ok up to the line that starts "final boolean useStandardEnding", that was the easy part.. I included the code for the whole function to give the whole picture.
I made an attempt at the next line and the IF statement, but then it starts talking about XOR and I just don't know where to start with the coding for that..
I understand the concept of XOR but so far have never needed to actually code it..

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class TokenDecode {

  /**
   * Method to decode the User token
   * 
   * @param UserId
   * @return long - unique decoded id
   */
  public static long decode(final String UserId) {

    final int FILL_CHAR_EQUAL = 1;
    int type = 0;
    if (UserId == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("UserId can't be null");
    }

    if (UserId.endsWith("=")) {
      // new encoding
      type = 1;
    } else {
      // old encoding
      type = 2;
    }

    final boolean useStandardEnding = (type == FILL_CHAR_EQUAL);
    byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(UserId, useStandardEnding);
    if (bytes.length < 40) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          "Base64 decoded length of UserId should be 40 (Actual="
              + bytes.length + ";UserId=" + UserId + ")");
    }

    // exclusive or
    byte[] xor = { (byte) 0xa0, (byte) 0xb2, (byte) 0x91, (byte) 0x20 };
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        bytes[cnt] = (byte) (bytes[cnt] ^ xor[j]);
        cnt++;
      }
      xor[3] += 4;
    }
    // rotate right 2 entities
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[8];
    System.arraycopy(bytes, 32, buffer, 0, 8);
    System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, bytes, 8, 32);
    System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, bytes, 0, 8);
    // remove leading '=' and convert to int
    String str = new String(bytes);
    final int pos = str.lastIndexOf('=');
    str = str.substring(pos + 1);
    // Added to remove the extra spaces in the userid
    // Integration.
    str = (str == null) ? null : str.trim();
    return Long.parseLong(str);
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If there is an online converter that will do this, then pointing me in the direction of it would also be helpful.. I just couldn't find one and when people asked on SO everyone seemed to be saying "do it by hand".. :-(

Comment: The xor operator is the same in Java and C# so what is it you don't understand?

Comment: @Ads OK I want to help. how can I do it other than writing all the code for you? (BTW: SO is not for site recommendation)

Comment: @I4V
I know the easy stuff, like the loops, variable declarations, etc.
If you'd like to help without coding it, ummm.. can you explain what is going on mainly around the byte array bits and the XOR parts..

Comment: @BrianRasmussen I understand the concept of XOR, but I don't know what it's trying to achieve so don't know how to rewrite it in .net

Comment: @Ads `can you explain what is going on mainly around the byte array bits and the XOR parts` Nothing is different in c#. Same logic as in java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't check the output with java since I don't have it installed on this pc. I wrote it as fast as I could and I'm a little rusty on java... just try and see whether this works:

```
    public static long Decode(String UserId)
    {
        int FILL_CHAR_EQUAL = 1;
        int type = 0;
        if (UserId == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("UserId can't be null");
        }

        if (UserId.EndsWith("="))
        {
            // new encoding
            type = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            // old encoding
            type = 2;
        }

        bool useStandardEnding = (type == FILL_CHAR_EQUAL);
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(UserId);
        if (bytes.Length < 40)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "Base64 decoded length of UserId should be 40 (Actual="
                    + bytes.Length + ";UserId=" + UserId + ")");
        }

        // exclusive or
        byte[] xor = new byte[] { (byte)0xa0, (byte)0xb2, (byte)0x91, (byte)0x20 };
        int cnt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                bytes[cnt] = (byte)(bytes[cnt] ^ xor[j]);
                cnt++;
            }
            xor[3] += 4;
        }
        // rotate right 2 entities
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8];
        Array.Copy(bytes, 32, buffer, 0, 8);
        Array.Copy(bytes, 0, bytes, 8, 32);
        Array.Copy(buffer, 0, bytes, 0, 8);
        // remove leading '=' and convert to int
        String str = Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes);
        int pos = str.LastIndexOf('=');
        str = str.Substring(pos + 1);
        // Added to remove the extra spaces in the userid-ebay-PayPal
        // Integration.
        str = (str == null) ? null : str.Trim();
        return long.Parse(str);
    }
```